# Problems with \smashoperator: Limit controls must follow a math operator

Tags: spacing, errors

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{mleftright}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{braket}

\newcommand\equalhat{\mathrel{\stackon[1.5pt]{=}{\stretchto{%
    \scalerel*[\widthof{=}]{\wedge}{\rule{1ex}{3ex}}}{0.5ex}}}}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\underbrace{\hat{\rho'}_{ss}^{ \mleft( 2 \mright) } \equalhat \hat{\rho'}_{ss}^{ \mleft( 1 \mright) }}_{\smashoperator[b]{of \, equivalent \, form}} & = \Tr^{ \mleft( 2 \mright) } \mleft( \hat{\rho}_{ss} \mright) = \sum_{\bullet \in \{ \uparrow, \downarrow \} } \bra{\bullet}^{ \mleft( 2 \mright) } \mleft( \ket{ss} \bra{ss} \mright) \ket{\bullet}^{ \mleft( 2 \mright) } \nonumber \\
        & = \frac{1}{2} ( \bra{\uparrow}^{ \mleft( 2 \mright) } \mleft( \ket{\uparrow \downarrow} \bra{\uparrow \downarrow} - \ket{\uparrow \downarrow} \bra{\downarrow \uparrow} - \ket{\downarrow \uparrow} \bra{\uparrow \downarrow} + \ket{\downarrow \uparrow} \bra{\downarrow \uparrow} \mright) \ket{\uparrow}^{ \mleft( 2 \mright) } \nonumber \\
        & \quad \, + \bra{\downarrow}^{ \mleft( 2 \mright) } \mleft( \ket{\uparrow \downarrow} \bra{\uparrow \downarrow} - \ket{\uparrow \downarrow} \bra{\downarrow \uparrow} - \ket{\downarrow \uparrow} \bra{\uparrow \downarrow} + \ket{\downarrow \uparrow} \bra{\downarrow \uparrow} \mright) \ket{\downarrow}^{ \mleft( 2 \mright) } ) \nonumber \\
        & = \frac{1}{2} \mleft( \ket{\downarrow}^{ \mleft( 1 \mright) } \bra{\downarrow}^{ \mleft( 1 \mright) } + \ket{\uparrow}^{ \mleft( 1 \mright) } \bra{\uparrow}^{ \mleft( 1 \mright) } \mright) \, .
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

produces the error: Limit controls must follow a math operator.

What do I have to change? I have the horizontal space that what is under the underbrace takes up to be ignored for other objects (they are right of it).

[The other questions on here with the same error were typos or the suggestion was to not load certain interfering packages.
A) which package would that be and
B) since this is part of a large document I'm not sure this is a viable option.

EDIT:
I now remember that I meant to use \smash[b] and that works. \smashoperator only takes [l] and [r] as arguments as Mico pointed out.

Answer (score 5):

`\smashoperator` produces a *horizontal* smashing, so the optional argument can be `[l]` or `[r]` (default is `[c]`). Maybe this code , with some slight improvements (e.g. using medium-sized fraction for the numerical coefficients), produces what you want?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{mleftright}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{nccmath, mathtools}
\usepackage{braket}

\newcommand\equalhat{\mathrel{\stackon[1.5pt]{=}{\stretchto{%
    \scalerel*[\widthof{=}]{ ∧ }{\rule{1ex}{3ex}}}{0.5ex}}}}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\underbrace{\hat{\rho'}_{ss}^{ \mleft( 2 \mright) } \equalhat \hat{\rho'}_{ss}^{ \mleft( 1 \mright) }}_{%\smashoperator[b]{
\clap{\footnotesize of equivalent form}}
 & = \Tr^{ \mleft( 2 \mright) } \mleft( \hat{ρ}_{ss} \mright) = \smashoperator{\sum_{\bullet \in \{ \uparrow, \downarrow \} } }\bra{\bullet}^{ \mleft( 2 \mright) } \mleft( \ket{ss} \bra{ss} \mright) \ket{\bullet}^{ \mleft( 2 \mright) } \nonumber \\
        & = \smash{\mfrac{1}{2}}\mleft( \bra{\uparrow}^{ \mleft( 2 \mright) } \mleft( \ket{\uparrow \downarrow} \bra{\uparrow \downarrow} - \ket{\uparrow \downarrow} \bra{\downarrow \uparrow} - \ket{\downarrow \uparrow} \bra{\uparrow \downarrow} + \ket{\downarrow \uparrow} \bra{\downarrow \uparrow} \mright) \ket{\uparrow}^{ \mleft( 2 \mright) }\mright. \nonumber \\
        & \quad \mleft. + \bra{\downarrow}^{ \mleft( 2 \mright) } \mleft( \ket{\uparrow \downarrow} \bra{\uparrow \downarrow} - \ket{\uparrow \downarrow} \bra{\downarrow \uparrow} - \ket{\downarrow \uparrow} \bra{\uparrow \downarrow} + \ket{\downarrow \uparrow} \bra{\downarrow \uparrow} \mright) \ket{\downarrow}^{ \mleft( 2 \mright) }\mright) \nonumber \\
        & = \mfrac{1}{2} \mleft( \ket{\downarrow}^{ \mleft( 1 \mright) } \bra{\downarrow}^{ \mleft( 1 \mright) } + \ket{\uparrow}^{ \mleft( 1 \mright) } \bra{\uparrow}^{ \mleft( 1 \mright) } \mright) \, .
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico: This happens when I close the edit window, and reopen it, and  the equation is rather long, I didn't notice it. Thanks for for pointing it!

Answer (score 4):

`\smashoperator` is a macro provided by the `mathtools` package. Its argument *must* contain an "operator", such as `\sum`, `\prod`, or `\int` and its arguments, e.g., the indices of summation or the lower and upper limits of integration. `\smashoperator` can take an optional argument -- either `[l]` or `[r]` -- to indicate that the "smashing" should be limited on the left or the right.

Your code, in contrast, contains

```
\underbrace{...}_{\smashoperator[b]{of \, equivalent \, form}}
```

Not an operator in sight, is there? Moreover, the `[b]` option cannot go over well either.

What you *should* be writing is

```
\underbrace{...}_{\mathclap{\text{of equivalent form}}}
```

`\mathclap` is also defined by the `mathtools` package.

---

*Addendum*: Here's a full version of your equation, which applies both `\smash[b]` and `\mathclap` to the underbrace term *and* a `\smashoperator` directive aimed at the `\sum` term. I've also gotten rid of all `\mleft` and `\mright` wrappers, as they either do nothing (except create code clutter) or fail to produce larger parentheses.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{stackengine, % 'amsmath' is loaded by 'mathtools'
            scalerel,mathtools,braket}
\newcommand\equalhat{\mathrel{\stackon[1.5pt]{=}{\stretchto{%
    \scalerel*[\widthof{=}]{\wedge}{\rule{1ex}{3ex}}}{0.5ex}}}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\smash[b]{\underbrace{\hat{\rho'}_{ss}^{(2)} \equalhat \hat{\rho'}_{ss}^{(1)}}_{%
   \mathclap{\text{of equivalent form}}}}
&= \Tr^{(2)} (\hat{\rho}_{ss}) = 
\smashoperator{\sum_{\bullet \in \{ \uparrow,\downarrow \} }} \bra{\bullet}^{(2)} 
\bigl( \ket{ss} \bra{ss} \bigr) \ket{\bullet}^{(2)} \nonumber \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \Bigl[ \bra{\uparrow}^{(2)} 
\bigl(  \ket{\uparrow\downarrow} \bra{\uparrow\downarrow} 
      - \ket{\uparrow\downarrow} \bra{\downarrow\uparrow} 
      - \ket{\downarrow\uparrow} \bra{\uparrow\downarrow} 
      + \ket{\downarrow\uparrow} \bra{\downarrow\uparrow} 
      \bigr) \ket{\uparrow}^{(2)} \nonumber \\
&\qquad + \bra{\downarrow}^{(2)} 
\bigl( \ket{\uparrow\downarrow} \bra{\uparrow\downarrow} 
     - \ket{\uparrow\downarrow} \bra{\downarrow\uparrow} 
     - \ket{\downarrow\uparrow} \bra{\uparrow\downarrow} 
     + \ket{\downarrow\uparrow} \bra{\downarrow\uparrow} 
     \bigr) \ket{\downarrow}^{(2)} \Bigr] \nonumber \\[1ex]
&= \frac{1}{2} \bigl( \ket{\downarrow}^{(1)} \bra{\downarrow}^{(1)} 
   + \ket{\uparrow}^{(1)} \bra{\uparrow}^{(1)} \bigr) \, .
\end{align}
\end{document}
```